# KeyCloak fails to send email using SMTP with status 500

Tags: email, smtp, keycloak, sendgrid

I have Keycloak running in a Kubernetes cluster. Authentication works but I need to set up e-mail to be able to send e-mails for verification and password reset.

I have [SendGrid set up as an SMTP Relay](https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/integrating-with-the-smtp-api). These settings (host, port and api key) work when I send mail using the [SendGrid java client](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-java). However, when pressing `Test connection` in KeyCloak I get:

```
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 () 
[Debug] Remove message (services.js, line 14)
[Debug] Added message (services.js, line 15)
[Error] Can't find variable: error
https://<domain>/auth/resources/ong8v/admin/keycloak/js/controllers/realm.js:76 – "Possibly unhandled rejection: {}"
[Debug] Remove message (services.js, line 14)
```

There isn't much to go on here. I have an e-mail address set up for the currently logged in user. I've also tried resetting the password in case the `Test connection` functionality was broken but that didn't work either.

The `Realm Settings` settings user for email are as such:

```
host: smtp.sendgrid.net
port: 587
from: test@<domain>
Enable StartTLS: true
Username: "apikey"
Password: <api key>
```

Any idea what can be wrong? Or how to find out? For instance, maybe I can get a more meaningful error message somehow.

---

Edit:

I got the server logs.

```
Failed to send email: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.sendgrid.net, 587; timeout 10000;
nested exception is: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
```

---

Edit 2:

I've tried sending mail using Telnet using the exact same settings and that works. So apparently it's something with Keycloak or its underlying Java libraries that's causing issues sending e-mail.

Comment: check with turning off the TLS, i faced similar issue was using the gmail smtp but forget what was actual solution.

Comment: I have the option of turning on and off SSL and TLS. I've tried combination of on and off with no luck unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that Keycloak works and that emails were blocked by the hosting provider.

Comment: Hello! I'm facing the exact same symptoms, but I don't know how I can check whether it's the hosting provider that's blocking emails in my case as well. Any advice?

Comment: Found my problem: my keycloak server was blocking ports 25, 465 and 587 as default behaviour 

Comment: I used ports rather than blocked ones. for aws ses I used port 2465, not 465 and it worked